# Sending an email from a node.js client with a service account

Tags: node.js, google-api, gmail-api

So i have the following code:

```
var Path = require('path');
var google = require('googleapis');
var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
var key = require(Path.join(__dirname, 'googleConfig.json'));
var oAuthClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'],
    null
);

var message = new Buffer(
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
    "To: <some email>\n" +
    "From: <some email>\n" +
    "Subject: something something lol\n\n" +
    "heyheyhey"
).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: oAuthClient,
    userId: '<my own google email?>',
    resource: {
        raw: message
    }
}, function(err, resp) {
    console.log('err', err);
    console.log('resp', resp);
});
```

And i use the same generated key to my google calendar API, so the service account is active and working.

I get the following error:

```
{ [Error: Bad Request]
  code: 400,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'failedPrecondition',
       message: 'Bad Request' } ] }
```

Is it correct to assume that the userId is my own google email account?
i have allso tried to use the `key.client_email` and `client_id`  instead, which didn't work.

Im really quite lost :)  any help, or even just tips on how to debug it would be awesome.

Btw, i did activate the gmail API on console.developers

Answer (score 1):

With service account you cannot use your own gmail account.

With service account you can impersonate users in a domain only if [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation) is implemented in that domain.

In that parameter you can use the value 'me', which takes the email of the authenticated user, in this case the service account email.

Instead of sending 'resource' try sending 'message', like in the javascript example in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send).

If you want to send the email from your own gmail account, then you will have to implement normal [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).